# symfony3 Configuration Checker

Tags: php, symfony

Recently, I have installed symfony 3.0.* , after that i execute this url:

http://localhost/symfony3/web/config.php

and i got this issue:

intl ICU version installed on your system (56.1) should match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (55.1)

In most cases you should be fine, but please verify there is no inconsistencies between data provided by Symfony and the intl extension. See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15007 for an example of inconsistencies you might run into.

Do you know whats happens?

Comment: Hi Diego. If I answered your question, then you should click the checkmark besides my answer to indicated that. I'm thinking you may be new to stackoverflow and may not be aware of the procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this message.
Just make sure you got the GREEN [OK].

You should see this when running from command line like so:

```
php bin/symfony_requirements
```

Then if you see a Green [OK] message, then everything is fine!